# How to Execute Python Code on Server from an HTML Form Button

Tags: python, ajax, button, flask, forms, http-post

I want to execute python code when user clicks an HTML Form Button. How is it going to be possible? Is it possible that users are not able to view the python code on the server? The forms input are going to be variables in the python code. I am using Flask framework and python 2.7. Security is not a concern yet.

my route.py file:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from moviepy.editor import *
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def landing():
    return render_template("index.html",ytdir=ytdir,ytlink=ytlink)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The index.html in the Template folder:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ytdir" placeholder="Example: C:\Downloads">

<h4>The YouTube Video that you want to download</h4>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="ytlink" placeholder="Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HipaBLsGB_Y"></textarea>
</form>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Download">
```

basically, I have a python code that download the YouTube video into the local drive by using `ytdir` and `ytlink`.

Where should I place the python code so that it is executed when the button is clicked.

Comment: You want the clients computer to execute the python script?

Comment: I want the client's computer to submit a Post request to my server. My server then takes the input fields and run a python script. In this example, the client's computer inputs a youtube link. Then, my server has a python script to download the youtube video. I have a working python script. I just don't know how to get my server to execute this python code after clicking the submit button.

Comment: I understand, and that is a really common use pattern. In fact it is so common that Flask has a tutorial on [how to do AJAX with jQuery and Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend for you to do an "api call"

```
@app.route("/ytdl", methods=["GET"])
def download_video(link):
 # call your download code here 
 # and return the video as an input stream
 # read the flask tutorial on how to do that
```

In the javascript use axios or something to download the file using jquery 
like `$button.click(() => axios.get(http://<localhost url>:<port>/ytdl)` go and read the doc again how to do ajax call